# How to scroll PyGTK ScrolledWindow to a certain row of a nested table?

Tags: pygtk, scrolledwindow

I have a program in PyGTK which has a ScrolledWindow and a Table nested in it. The table rows can be of a different height. What I'm trying to find is a way to scroll the view so it begins from the selected row. I know how to move the scrollbar to a certain position using the scrolled_window.get_vadjustment().set_value(), but I do not know how to find the scroll position of the table rows.

Alternatively, maybe I'm using wrong widget and someone can point me to the right one? I'm trying to achieve the following behaviour: the screen shows the rows of a table, the top row is the currently selected object, when the user presses up or down buttons, the whole table scrolls down or up, so the previous or the next row becomes the top row.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found a solution: you have to use the child widget get_allocation() function, which returns the bounding rectangle of a child widget relative to the scrolledwindow, so child.get_allocation().y is the answer to my own question.